# What is the equivalent of sklearn's `random_state` for XGBoost?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, kaggle

I can't seem to get XGBoost to give me the same results twice in a row. In sklearn, I seem to be able to use random_state but this does not work in XGBoost.

I've also tried setting the `seed`, `subsample`, `colsample_bytree` (setting `subsample` and `colsample_bytree` to 1 doesn't seem to make a difference).

Any suggestion on how I can reproduce the result, sort of like setting the `random_state` value in sklearn?

Here's some of the code for thoroughness, but I think you may want to look at the model specifically at the bottom of my question.

### Preprocessing

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

#numerical columns
numerical_columns_list = [colname for colname in X_train.columns if
                    X_train[colname].dtypes in ['int64', 'float64']]

X_train_trf = X_train.copy()
X_valid_trf = X_valid.copy()

# Preprocessing for numerical data
num_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
X_train_trf[numerical_columns_list] = num_imputer.fit_transform(X_train_trf[numerical_columns_list])
X_valid_trf[numerical_columns_list] = num_imputer.transform(X_valid_trf[numerical_columns_list])

# Preprocessing for categorical data

categorical_columns_list = [colname for colname in X_train.columns if
                    X_train[colname].dtypes == 'object' ]

cat_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
X_train_trf[categorical_columns_list] = cat_imputer.fit_transform(X_train_trf[categorical_columns_list])
X_valid_trf[categorical_columns_list] = cat_imputer.transform(X_valid_trf[categorical_columns_list])

le = LabelEncoder()
for col in X_train_trf[categorical_columns_list].columns:
    X_train_trf[col] = le.fit_transform(X_train_trf[col])
    X_valid_trf[col] = le.fit_transform(X_valid_trf[col])
```

### Model

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.05,
                     subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree= 0.8, seed=42)

model.fit(X_train_trf,y_train,
        early_stopping_rounds=5,
        eval_set=[(X_train_trf, y_train), (X_valid_trf, y_valid)],
        verbose=False)
preds = model.predict(X_valid_trf)
```

Comment: Is there any randomness in your data spliting?

Comment: Great question. I'm not sure checking

Comment: Here's the link to the notebook for reference   https://www.kaggle.com/calvinbroadus/xgboost-model/

Comment: Ah, you were right on point. For reference, setting `random_state` to train_test_split fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the issue was not so much with XGBoost but with the data splitting. Thanks Venkatachalam for pointing it out!

I was splitting the data with `train_test_split` without setting the `random_state`!

Fixed as below:

```
X_train_full, X_valid_full, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_full, y,
  train_size=0.8, test_size = 0.2, random_state=1)
```